# All Timestamp date reduces by 2 hours, Java 1.7 and MS SQL Server

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I developed a Spring based Rest API, returning a list of DTO's. In my DTO I have some fields having TimeStamp as a DataType. While I try to debug, the API is returning the values well and good, Only Problem is all the timestamp values are getting reduced by 2 hours. For Example: It should return

> 2019-09-04 00:00:00.000,

but it returns

> 2019-09-03T22:00:00Z

I have already tried to change my PC's date and time to see if there is some effect, but no help

```
@GetMapping("/")
public ResponseEntity<List<ActionCustomDto>> getAllActions(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam(value = "ncId", required = true) List<String> ncIdList, @RequestParam(value = "actionPlan", required = true) List<String> actionPlanList) {
    LOGGER.info("Fetching Action List with the following params : ncIdList = " + ncIdList + ", actionPlanList = " + actionPlanList);
    // String user = request.getHeader("X-User-Login");
    // LOGGER.info("Retrieved user ad login : " + user);

    List<String> exactActionPlans = this.populateExactActionPlans(actionPlanList);
    List<ActionCustomDto> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (final String ncId : ncIdList) {

        List<ActionPlanDto> actionPlans = this.actionPlanService.findRequiredActionPlans(ncId, exactActionPlans);

        for (ActionPlanDto actionPlan : actionPlans) {
            List<ActionDto> actions = this.actionService.findRequiredActions(actionPlan.getActionPlanId());
            for (ActionDto action : actions) {
                ActionCustomDto actionCustomDto = new ActionCustomDto();
                this.populateActionCustomDto(actionCustomDto, action, ncId);
                result.add(actionCustomDto);
            }
        }
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(result);
}

private void populateActionCustomDto(ActionCustomDto actionCustomDto, ActionDto action, String ncId) {

    actionCustomDto.setActionDescription(action.getActionDescription());
    actionCustomDto.setStartDate(action.getStartDate());
    actionCustomDto.setDueDate(action.getDueDate());
    actionCustomDto.setAssigneeResponse(action.getActionResponse());
    actionCustomDto.setActionStatus(action.getActionStatus());
    actionCustomDto.setIsDeleted(action.getIsDeleted());
}
```

public class ActionCustomDto {

```
private String actionDescription;

private Timestamp startDate;

private Timestamp dueDate;

private String assigneeResponse;

private String actionStatus;

private Boolean isDeleted;

public String getActionDescription() {
    return this.actionDescription;
}

public void setActionDescription(String actionDescription) {
    this.actionDescription = actionDescription;
}

public Timestamp getStartDate() {
    return this.startDate;
}

public void setStartDate(Timestamp startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}

public Timestamp getDueDate() {
    return this.dueDate;
}

public void setDueDate(Timestamp dueDate) {
    this.dueDate = dueDate;
}

public String getAssigneeResponse() {
    return this.assigneeResponse;
}

public void setAssigneeResponse(String assigneeResponse) {
    this.assigneeResponse = assigneeResponse;
}

public String getActionStatus() {
    return this.actionStatus;
}

public void setActionStatus(String actionStatus) {
    this.actionStatus = actionStatus;
}


public List<String> getSerialNumbers() {
    return this.serialNumbers;
}

public void setSerialNumbers(List<String> serialNumbers) {
    this.serialNumbers = serialNumbers;
}

public Boolean getIsDeleted() {
    return this.isDeleted;
}

public void setIsDeleted(Boolean isDeleted) {
    this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
}
```

}

Actual Result:

```
actionDescription: "action description 1",
startDate: "2019-09-03T22:00:00Z",
dueDate: "2019-09-03T22:00:00Z",
assigneeResponse: "",
actionStatus: "Action-Assigned-New",
isDeleted: false
}
```

Expected Result:

```
actionDescription: "action description 1",
startDate: "2019-09-04 00:00:00.000",
dueDate: "2019-09-04 00:00:00.000",
assigneeResponse: "",
actionStatus: "Action-Assigned-New",
isDeleted: false
}
```

Comment: Where do you get your timestamps from? Maybe there's a timezone mismatch between some database and your application?

Comment: what Database are you using?

Comment: How do you convert the timestamp into a string? Seems a timezone problem. Maybe the difference between UTC and your local timezone

Comment: Given the 2 hour timezone offset this is very likely a timezone issue.  One part is expecting 0 timezone offset.  Some part is compensating to put things in UTC.

Comment: I see your local time has zone +02:00. The actual result is probably expressed in UTC

Comment: Database is MS SQL Server and Java version is 1.7

Answer (score 1):

First of all, keep in mind that the `Z` in the end of the date means *UTC* (or *zero offset from UTC*).

> In my DTO I have some fields having `Timestamp` as a data type.

Since Java 8, [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html) and their friends such as [`Time`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Time.html), [`Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Timestamp.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html) and [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) are *legacy classes*. They are not deprecated (yet), but you should avoid then. In your situation, you could either use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) or [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

For Java 7 and below, you may want to consider the [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project: id brings a backport of Java 8 date and time classes to Java 6 and 7, so you can use [`Instant`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/Instant.html) or [`OffsetDateTime`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/OffsetDateTime.html).

If using the backport, for some reason, is not an option, then you could consider setting a timezone for Jackson:

```java
spring.jackson.time-zone: UTC
```

Comment: Using Java 7, that's the problem

Comment: @MohdSalim Then you may look into the [`ThreeTen Backport`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project.

Comment: @MohdSalim Also try setting the timezone for Jackson: `spring.jackson.time-zone: <value>`.

Answer (score 0):

Change timestamp for ZonedDateTime, and gonna gave you the actual date, with the zoned time.

Comment: Java 7 is being used

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... Is it MySQL? Try specifying both server and local timezone on your connection string. My MySQL server, running on Docker, somehow would not detect it's timezone correctly. This fixed it for me:

jdbc:mysql://server:3306/database?useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8&serverTimezone=America/Sao_Paulo&sessionVariables=time_zone='America/Sao_Paulo'

Answer (score 0):

The configuration `time zone` of your DB must be `UTC +0`. So when you insert some `date`, it will change automatically to `UTC +0`.

For this reason when you get this data, you see the date 2 hours less, as your local time is `UTC +2`.

Moreover, you can't set a value in a particular time zone with `Timestamp`.

To solve this you must either declare a `SimpleDateFormat` to reajust your `Dates` or change the `time zone` configuration of your DB.

Comment: Yes, Correct! I just solved it by changing the getter
 @JsonGetter("dueDate")
 public String getDueDate() {
  if (this.dueDate != null) {
   return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'H:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").format(this.dueDate);
  } else {
   return null;
  }
 }